# Doing a BFS proper coloring on a graph

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, graph-coloring

Starting from Vertex 0 I'm then assigning the color 1 to vertex 0, then assign a color to all of the vertices that are neighbors of vertex 0, then assign a color to all the vertices whose shortest distance to vertex 0 is 2, and so forth, until all of the vertices are colored. I'm running into a problem when when running my code the "colors" for my graph are always returning 0. 
the output from the program should be

```
0 1
1   2
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   1
8   2
```

but all I'm getting in return is

```
0 0  
1   0    
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0    
6   0    
7   0    
8   0
```

I Posted the code that I'm running below, any help would be greatly appreciated in trying to solve this, keep in mind I have a separate class that calls this and runs in.

```
public class P7BFSColorGraph {
int[] colorArray;
ArrayList<Integer> colorList;


public P7BFSColorGraph(Graph G) {
    colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    colorArray = new int[G.V()];


    SimplerBreadthFirstPaths graph = new SimplerBreadthFirstPaths(G,0);
    for(int dis=0;dis<G.V();dis++) {
        for(int ver=0;ver<G.V();ver++) {
            if(graph.distTo(ver) == dis) {
                if (colorArray[ver] != 0)
                    colorList.add(colorArray[ver]);
                findUnusedColor(colorList);
                colorArray[ver] = findUnusedColor(colorList);
            }
        }

    }

}

public int vertexColor(int v ) {
    if(colorArray[v] != 0) {
        return colorArray[v];
    }
    return 0;
}

private int findUnusedColor(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    list.sort(null);
    list.add(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i+1)-list.get(i)>1) {
            return list.get(i)+1;
        }
    }
    return list.get(list.size()-1)+1;
}
```

}

Comment: What algorithm are you attempting to implement? Or is it one of your own invention?

Comment: @Diasiare its a simper version of the breath first search

Comment: Breadth first search isn't a graph coloring algorithm, it's a graph traversal algorithm, which is an important part of coloring. however normally picking a color is more complex. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  @Diasiare has raised a good point (how Coloring differs from traversing).  Your approach should guarantee that no two adjacent vertices have the same color, but I'm not certain it will generate the desired result.  If it does not, can you please edit your question to include the input graph, showing the nodes and edges.

Possible solution:

The issue your code has relates to not having a reference between a distance and it's color.  A `Map` would be a good choice here, but sticking with your code style an array called `distArray` will be used.  This array holds the color for the given distance.  New colors are assigned as needed (when a new distance is detected).  To follow will produce the results you expect.

```
List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] colorArray = new int[G.V()];
int[] distArray = new int[G.V()];
SimplerBreadthFirstPaths graph = new SimplerBreadthFirstPaths(G,0);

for (int dis = 0; dis < G.V(); dis++) {
    for (int ver = 0; ver < G.V(); ver++) {
        if (G.distTo(ver) == dis) {
            if (distArray[dis] == 0) {
                // Only assign a new color when a new distance occurs
                distArray[dis] = findUnusedColor(colorList);
                colorList.add(distArray[dis]);
            } 
            // Assign the color based on it's distance
            colorArray[ver] = distArray[dis];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a more efficient way to run the algorithm (there is no need for a double loop which is O(n^2) - you can run this in O(n)

```
for (int ver = 0; ver < G.V(); ver++) {
    int dis = G.distTo(ver);
    if (distArray[dis] == 0) {
        distArray[dis] = findUnusedColor(colorList);
        colorList.add(distArray[dis]);
    }
    colorArray[ver] = distArray[dis];
}
```